# How to set zoom origin for a QML Chart View

Tags: qt, qml, qtcharts

I am developing a data presentation application using QT QML with QTCharts. I am using a ChartView and a line series to show XY data. Everything works apart from pinching and zooming the graph. The application is targeting mobile touch device.

I want to be able to pinch and zoom the graph and set the zoom origin to the center of the pinch. Currently, I have it working but the graph only zooms from the center of the graph at all times.

Is this possible in QML?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use the [`zoomIn(rect rectangle)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#zoomIn-method-1) method that can receive as a parameter the rectangle that will be visible, in your case the rectangle must have as center the point where you click.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        anchors.fill: parent
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
        antialiasing: true

        LineSeries {
            name: "LineSeries"
            XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 2.1 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 3.3 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 4.9 }
            XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 3.0 }
            XYPoint { x: 4.1; y: 3.3 }
        }

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: chartView.zoomReset();
        }

        PinchArea{
            id: pa
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPinchUpdated: {
                chartView.zoomReset();
                var center_x = pinch.center.x
                var center_y = pinch.center.y
                var width_zoom = height/pinch.scale;
                var height_zoom = width/pinch.scale;
                var r = Qt.rect(center_x-width_zoom/2, center_y - height_zoom/2, width_zoom, height_zoom)
                chartView.zoomIn(r)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked into the zoom in text but I cannot figure out how to define the size of the rect when using a pinch gesture.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have looked into using the zoom in rect. But I cannot figure out how to dynamically create the rect using a pinch gestures information.

Comment: @MartinSmith 
Okay, I just understood that you wanted to use Pinch Gesture, try my updated solution.

Comment: Brilliant, I will try this today and get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It nearly works. The problem is when the chart zooms. It moves the contents of the zoom rect to the center of the chart view. I understand that this is what the zoomIn(rect) function is supposed to do. so im starting to think that this kind of functionality cannot be achieved with the QT Chartview.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank eyllanesc for putting me on the rigth track with his answer. I made a few improvements to add the ability to compound successive pinch motions and to drag the chart with a dragging gesture. I also reversed the pinch dragging motion so the chart will move as if it were dragged by the moving pinch (instead of moving in the opposite direction with the original code). The scale is applied in the direction of the pinch angle, i.e. if pinched vertically, only the Y axis will be zoomed in. Pinching at a 45-degree angle applies an equal zoom to both axes. This gives it a more intuitive feel.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0
    
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
       id: chart
       anchors.fill: parent
       theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
       antialiasing: true

       LineSeries {
           name: "LineSeries"
           XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
           XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 2.1 }
           XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 3.3 }
           XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
           XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 4.9 }
           XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 3.0 }
           XYPoint { x: 4.1; y: 3.3 }
       }
       PinchArea{
           id: pa
           anchors.fill: parent
           property real currentPinchScaleX: 1
           property real currentPinchScaleY: 1
           property real pinchStartX : 0
           property real pinchStartY : 0

           onPinchStarted: {
               // Pinching has started. Record the initial center of the pinch
               // so relative motions can be reversed in the pinchUpdated signal
               // handler
               pinchStartX = pinch.center.x;
               pinchStartY = pinch.center.y;
           }

           onPinchUpdated: {
               chart.zoomReset();

               // Reverse pinch center motion direction
               var center_x = pinchStartX + (pinchStartX - pinch.center.x);
               var center_y = pinchStartY + (pinchStartY - pinch.center.y);

               // Compound pinch.scale with prior pinch scale level and apply
               // scale in the absolute direction of the pinch gesture
               var scaleX = currentPinchScaleX * (1 + (pinch.scale - 1) * Math.abs(Math.cos(pinch.angle * Math.PI / 180)));
               var scaleY = currentPinchScaleY * (1 + (pinch.scale - 1) * Math.abs(Math.sin(pinch.angle * Math.PI / 180)));

               // Apply scale to zoom levels according to pinch angle
               var width_zoom = height / scaleX;
               var height_zoom = width / scaleY;

               var r = Qt.rect(center_x - width_zoom / 2, center_y - height_zoom / 2, width_zoom, height_zoom);
               chart.zoomIn(r);
           }

           onPinchFinished: {
               // Pinch finished. Record compounded pinch scale.
               currentPinchScaleX = currentPinchScaleX * (1 + (pinch.scale - 1) * Math.abs(Math.cos(pinch.angle * Math.PI / 180)));
               currentPinchScaleY = currentPinchScaleY * (1 + (pinch.scale - 1) * Math.abs(Math.sin(pinch.angle * Math.PI / 180)));
           }

           MouseArea{
               anchors.fill: parent
               drag.target: dragTarget
               drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis

               onDoubleClicked: {                   
                   chart.zoomReset();
                   parent.currentPinchScaleX = 1;
                   parent.currentPinchScaleY = 1;
               }
           }

           Item {
               // A virtual item to receive drag signals from the MouseArea.
               // When x or y properties are changed by the MouseArea's
               // drag signals, the ChartView is scrolled accordingly.
               id: dragTarget

               property real oldX : x
               property real oldY : y

               onXChanged: {
                   chart.scrollLeft( x - oldX );
                   oldX = x;
               }
               onYChanged: {
                   chart.scrollUp( y - oldY );
                   oldY = y;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```