# Attaching MouseArea to ValueAxis

Tags: qml, qtcharts

I am adding zoom/pan capabilities to ChartView. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50052009/761090 shows wheel/pinch over the entire chart area, however, I would like to add separate `MouseArea` to each axis so that wheel events on that axis will zoom along that axis only (this way I will not have to convert coordinates, find out where the event is happening and so on). When I tried

```
ChartView{
   ValueAxis{
      id: _axisX
      MouseArea{               // <------- ERROR
         anchors.fill: parent
         onWheel: { ... }
      }
   }
   LineSeries{
      axisX: _axisX
      ...
   }
}
```

than I am getting `Cannot assign to non-existent default property` at the line indicated. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Attach `MouseArea` to the `ChartView`. `ValueAxis` doesn't derive from `Item` and so has no `data`, `children` or some another default property. `ValueAxis` is some kind of abstraction for just specified data providing.

Comment: Exactly, by design many of the elements are abstractions of what is drawn, the same happens with the XXXSeries.